# Passing data to a view loaded with res.redirect in express

Tags: javascript, express

Good morning all. I am trying to pass data to a view which is loaded in express via a redirect:

`res.redirect('/manage-account/2-0/returns/answers')`

The above is an html view which loads fine with just the redirect, but I want to pass some data. I can't pass data as part of a redirect, as far as I understand only a redirect?

So I have set up a `GET` for that route, and am trying to render the view with the data, but I am getting the error:

`template not found: /manage-account/2-0/returns/answers.html`

This is the route I created and how the page is initially redirected to in another view:

```
router.get('/manage-account/2-0/returns/questions', function (req, res) {
  // stuff

  res.redirect('/manage-account/2-0/returns/answers')
})

router.get('/manage-account/2-0/returns/answers', function (req, res) {
  res.render('/manage-account/2-0/returns/answers', { data })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the possible way to write.

Server Side `app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);` -

```
 app.get('/main', function(req, res) {

   var name = 'hello';

   res.render(__dirname + "/views/layouts/main.html", {name:name});

});
```

Client side (main.html) -

```
<h1><%= name %></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks pritam, I'm not sure how that applies to my scenario? Apologies if I am missing something.

Comment: Check your `view engine`, is that HTML or else.

Comment: The view engine is nunjucks

Comment: it's working for me, look like  - `nunjucks.configure('views', { autoescape: true, express: app });`, render like - `router.get('/', (req, res, next) => { res.render('index.html', { title: 'test-title' }); });` and in html - `<title><%= title %></title>`